# Ionic project won't build (or run) after android plugin updated to 2.2.0

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework

Error message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
  >   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
  >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
  >       Searched in the following locations:
  >           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom
  >           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.jar
  >       Required by:

  ```
      android:CordovaLib:unspecified
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Remove platforms/android folder and add Android again:

```
ionic platform add android
```

Answer (score 1):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    }
```

}

add jcenter() to your repositories.
this worked for me.

Comment: jcenter was already there. I added maven {...}, though, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but as the other answers didn't work hopefully this will help others

### Update your Android CordovaLib to the latest version

- https://cordova.apache.org/blog/
- Find the latest version and run the command given
- e.g. `cordova platform update android@6.1.0`

### If this is not possible (or doesn't work) manually change the file

**\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle** and add in jcenter()

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 buildscript {
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
 }
}
```

try modifying these in your build.gradle . good luck